# Upload or uploading?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

"At the time of this video's upload"

Is the "Upload" functioning as a noun adjective?

Also why is it written upload and not uploading, becuase in the sentence ("at the time of this writing") it's "writing" and not "write".

Comment: Either works in your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the noun upload, meaning 2

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/upload)

> n.
>   1. A file that is uploaded.
>   2. An instance of uploading data or a program.

There is no noun write.

Answer (score 0):

'Upload' is to do. 'Uploaded', done. 'Uploading' is being done. They can't be interchanged. Each word has a different meaning.

And uploading is what you are doing. It isn't which you have done before.
writing is a word of noun, because it has been written(the text)